# why is flexbox behaving like this?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a wholy grail template using flexbox and css. I'm new to this...

I have tried everything but i can not get the code to display in graphics (if that make sense). Please advise.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
      <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="flex-header">
        HEADER
    </header>
    <main class="flex-main">
        <nav class="flex-nav">
            SIDENAV
        </nav>
        <article class="flex-article">
            MAIN CONTENT
        </article>
        <aside class="flex-aside">
            SIDEBAR
        </aside>

    </main>
  <footer class="flex-footer">
    FOOTER
</footer> 

</body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
* {
margin: 2px; 
}
body {
font-size: 24px;
color: white;`
height: 100vh;
text-align: center;
}
.flex-header {
background-color: #5070B5;
padding-top: 3rem;
padding-bottom: 3rem;   
}
.flex-main {

}
.flex-nav {
background-color: #B95F21;
padding-top: 3rem;
}
.flex-article {
background-color: #81A43C;
padding-top: 3rem;
}
.flex-aside {
background-color: #B95F21;
padding-top: 3rem;
}
.flex-footer {
background-color: #5070B5;
padding-top: 3rem;
scroll-padding-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

It shows the text only, no graphics.

Comment: where is your page body content how anyone can understand your problem what your are actually facing.

Comment: Is your css file right next to your index(or whatever file) in your folder structure?

Comment: Also if that ' is not a typo that is your issue `line 6 in css: color: white;``

Answer (score 0):

Please check line 6 of your CSS `` color: white;` ``.

There is an invalid character `` ` `` at the end of the line. Such errors may cause browser to stop processing any further CSS.